# What is the difference between "before skip" and "before skip balanced" in a tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

I wish to disable the white space before my color box. While reading the documentation of `tcolorbox`, I found these two options:

[image]
[image]

The explanations given here are a little too technical for me, I cannot understand the difference between them. How should I choose between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that can illustrate the difference between the two options.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

text
\begin{tcolorbox}[before skip=0pt]
before skip
\end{tcolorbox}

text with depth
\begin{tcolorbox}[before skip=0pt]
before skip
\end{tcolorbox}

text
\begin{tcolorbox}[before skip balanced=0pt]
before skip balanced
\end{tcolorbox}

text with depth
\begin{tcolorbox}[before skip balanced=0pt]
before skip balanced
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: before skip examples]

The first two cases ignore baseline and the spacing with the preceding box is 0pt, while in the last two examples the spacing between the preceding baseline is 0.3\baselineskip.